# web2py - require selected dropdown values validate from db

Tags: python, web2py

i have a table member that include `SQLField("year", db.All_years)`

and All_years table as the following:

```
db.define_table("All_years",
  SQLField("fromY","integer"),
  SQLField("toY","integer")
  )
```

and constrains are :

```
db.member.year.requires = IS_IN_DB(db, 'All_years.id','All_years.fromY')
```

The problem is when I select a year from dropdown the value of year column is the id of year, not the year value e.g: if year 2009 has db id=1 the value of year in db equal=1 not equal 2009.

I don't understand why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see your project is progressing well!

The validator is `IS_IN_DB(dbset, field, label)`. So you should try:

```
db.member.year.requires = IS_IN_DB(db, 'All_years.id', '%(fromY)d')
```

to have a correct label in your drop-down list.

Now from your table it looks like you would rather choose an interval rather than just the beginning year, in that case you can use this:

```
db.member.year.requires = IS_IN_DB(db, 'All_years.id', '%(fromY)d to %(toY)d')
```

that will display, for example, "1980 to 1985", and so on.

Comment: The years values is displayed correct into drop-down but the incorrect scenario is, it saved the id of the selected year not the year number (e,x: 2009)

Comment: You mean in your field `year`? That's normal, you define your field as `db.All_years` which is a reference to another table, thus the id. That should not be an issue, to display it for example, you can use `rows = db(db.mytable.year == db.All_years.id).select(db.All_years.fromY, db.All_years.toY, ...)`.